# Lightroom: Import photos to folder in computer and backup in external hard disk?

Tags: lightroom, backup, import

I'm completely new to Lightroom, so I'm not able to understand features so easily.

All I want to do is this: 
When I insert the Memory card Lightroom asks for importing. I want to...

1. Import photos to a specific directory in my local computer and add to catalogue (adding to the catalogue is done while importing itself I guess).
2. After importing and adding to the catalogue, I want to backup the same photos to a specific
   Directory in external hard drive

Please help with steps as I'm very new to Lightroom. 
Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

When you open the import dialog in Lightroom, you have, at the top middle, (up to) four options: "Copy as DNG", "Copy", "Move", "Add". Adding to the catalog will be done in all cases.

- "Copy as DNG", "Copy" and "Move" copy your photos from their source to the folder you set on the right side.

  - "Copy as DNG" converts them to DNG in the process.
  - "Move" will delete the photos at the source side after copying.
- "Add" leaves the photos physically at the source side and only adds them to the catalog

So for your step 1, you'll want to select the "Copy" or "DNG" option.

For step 2 (create a backup copy), there's an option on the right side under "File Handling", called "Make a second copy to:" which ou have to check and set a path.

Furthermore, in the "Destination", you can set the path and some rules for automatic subfolders eg. based on the date.